# How to turn a signed integer value to unsigned, according to its bits?

Tags: c++, integer, int, uint8t

I want to turn a signed value into an unsigned one (for example, `int8_t` to `uint8_t`), but also it must keep its bits.

How can I do it?

Comment: How does one get a pint into a quart pot - http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+a+quart+into+a+pint+pot - The sign is important

Comment: See your bank statement for full details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice: you can simply assign the signed value to the `uint8_t`,

```
u = i;
```

or you can initialize it with the signed value,

```
uint8_t u = i;
```

This assumes a *two's complement* signed integer representation, which is universally used today. With that representation the bits are preserved exactly. The “in practice” qualification refers to that assumption.

---

E.g., on a modern machine, the 8-bit signed representation of e.g. −42, is bitpattern number −42 + 256, which is (bitpattern number) 214. Converting that to unsigned is guaranteed by the standard to yield the same value modulo 256. And so it's the same bitpattern, namely bitpattern 214.

---

Going from signed to unsigned is well defined by the standard, although the preservation of the bit pattern <sup>(1)</sup>generally is just an in-practice effect (all modern computers are designed that way). However, going in the opposite direction you encounter compiler-specific effects if the unsigned value cannot be represented. More care is needed for this conversion, because it's a matter of compiler discretion and not a practical guarantee at the hardware level.

---

<sup>(1) As M.M. explains in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34468484/464581) the particular signed type in your example, `int8_t`, is one that since C11 has been guaranteed two's complement in C. I do not see that language in the final draft of the C99 standard, so presumably it was not there in C99, and thus not in either C++11 or C++14, which are based on C99, but is probably there in C++17, which I believe is based on C11.</sup>

Comment: Unsigned integer wrapping is defined by the standard, independently of integer representation. (Signed wrapping is not.)

Comment: @JonPurdy: The bit you appear to missing in your view is that the standard allows tree different signed representations, of which only one guarantees to preserve the bitpattern when a value is converted to the corresponding unsigned type.

Comment: Ah, you’re right, I’d lost the context of the question while reading your answer. That’s what I get for having too many tabs open. Still, worth noting that simply initializing an unsigned value from a signed value doesn’t make any platform-specific assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

With the `intN_t` types you can simply write:

```
int8_t i = something;
uint8_t u = i;
```

because those types are required to use 2's complement representation, where this conversion is defined to preserve the bits.

Reference: C++14 [cstdint.syn]/2:

> The header defines all functions, types, and macros the same as 7.18 in the C standard

And C11 7.20.1.1/1 (C99 7.18.1.1):

> The typedef name `intN_t` designates a signed integer type with width `N`, no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation.

---

To preserve the representation for other integer types, use:

```
int i = something;
unsigned int i = *(unsigned int *)&i;
```

You can do this with any pair of corresponding signed and unsigned types. It is safe except for the possibility of generating a trap representation.

Comment: Please provide a source for "those types are required to use 2's complement representation".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf added

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that in C99, and didn't know it had been added.

Answer (score 0):

Try with explicit type conversion. The (unsafe) type conversion using static_cast is necessary to get to the "raw bytes" of a variable.
To convert the value of an to a given type, you write the following:

```
static_cast<type_to_convert_to>(expression)
```

With static_cast cast is checked statically in compile time.

```
#include <iostream>


int main() {

    int8_t i {11};
    uint8_t i2 = static_cast<uint8_t>(i);
    std::cout << "i occupies " <<  sizeof(i) << " bytes." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "i2 occupies " << sizeof(i2) << " bytes." << std::endl;


}
```